# Vimeo/Youtube playback Jquery .click() function... I don't even know how to word this question

Tags: jquery, video, click, embed

This is complicated.  Let's start with what I am doing.

I am using the Masonry Jquery Plugin (http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/docs/basic-single-column.html) to align a variety of divs (.box).   I am them using a script that will expand the div '.box' from it's original 200px width, to 400px in width.  When clicked again, the .box collapses.  This all works just fine.  View what I am doing here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanjay/fgNMJ/

What I want to do is also display videos.  Embed them either from YouTube or Vimeo(preference).  I can add the embed code from a Vimeo video into a .box and resize it using this Jquery code:

```
$('.video').css({
    width: '100%',
    height: 'auto'
});
```

The HTML would look like this:

```
<div class="box" id="videoBox">
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/16916715?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0" class="video"></iframe>
</div>
```

I've added a class "video" to the embed code.  This resizes the video to the correct dimensions of a width of 200px and a height of what ever it needs to be.  You can view what it looks like here: **http://jsfiddle.net/ryanjay/P3RBx/**

Now this is where is gets complicated and I don't even know where to start on making this work, or if it's possible.  When the video is clicked, I want it to expand to a width of 400px and a height of what ever it needs to be, auto, and then either start playing, or then the user can click play.

I had the idea of just making an image of the video, and then when that box is clicked it would hide the image, resize the box, then show the video, but I even ran into problems with that.

God I hope all this makes sense and I hope someone can help me. Ha.  Thinking about how to solve this is making my head melt.  If someone thinks they have an answer I would love it if you can put it into a jsFiddle document and show the entire code.  I am horrible at adding new code and it's taken forever just to get to this point.  I am new at all of this, and am slowly learning!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked of a script which gets the data required to play a vimeo video 
here is a link to the working model : http://jsfiddle.net/frictionless/UkNvM/2/

I had worked on a similar but not same requirements.Vimeo has a API which gives you all the details using the **videoID** 7100569 is the video ID of the video I want to get the info of.The info itself returned as JSONP contains the url for the player.

```
  $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.vimeo.com/api/v2/video/7100569.json?callback=?',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            url: url
        },
        success: function(data) {
            loadVimeoVideo(data, 'http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=' + url + '&callback=?')
        }
    })
```

Using the data obtained from this first request: where videoUrl is always of the form http://vimeo.com/XXXX and playerUrl is the data obtained from the first call. This call gets details the player itself as an iframe.

```
function loadVimeoPlayer(videoUrl, playerUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        url: playerUrl,
        data: {
            url: videoUrl
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var video = GetJson(data);
            if (!video || video == '') {
                $.Flash('error', 'The video could not be loaded. Please check the URL and the permissions, only Public videos can be added.');
                return;
            }
            var title = video.title;
            var author = video.author_name;
            var authorUrl = video.author_url;
            var htmlFrame = video.html;
            var width = video.width;
            var height = video.height;
            var duration = video.duration;
            var description = video.description;
            var thumbnailUrl = video.thumbnail_url;
            var thumbNailWidth = video.thumbnail_width;
            var thumbNailHeight = video.thumbnail_height;
            var videoId = video.video_id;
            var upload_date = video.upload_date;
            $('#player').html(htmlFrame);

        }
    });
}
```